# Zum „Hieressen“, „hier Essen“ oder „Hier-Essen“?

Tags: adverb, spelling, compound, nominalization

Wenn man was nicht in einem Restaurant, sondern anderswo bestellt, lautet oft die Frage:

> Zum Mitnehmen oder (zum) *hier essen?¹*

(Bestellt man z. B. einen Döner, so hört man ausnahmslos diese Frage.)

Weil niemand „zum hiesigen Verzehr“ oder so was in der Art sagt, vermute ich, dass diese Konstruktion in Ordnung ist. Folglich muss man auch die richtig schreiben können. **Wie?**

> 1. (…) zum Hier-Essen?
> 2. (…) zum Hier-essen?
> 3. (…) zum Hieressen?
> 4. (…) zum hier-essen? (eher unwahrscheinlich)
> 5. (…) zum hier-Essen? (eher unwahrscheinlich)
> 6. Sonst.

<sup>¹ An diesem Punkt soll Rechtschreibung Wurst sein. Denn die Frage dreht sich eben darum.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da ich hier mehrfach kreuz und quer Dinge brauche, beginne ich mit vier Zitaten aus den offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln:

---

> **§ 37** […] Partikeln können mit Substantiven Zusammensetzungen bilden. Man schreibt sie ebenso wie mehrteilige Substantivierungen zusammen.
>
> Dies betrifft:
> […]
> (2) Mehrteilige Substantivierungen, zum Beispiel:
> *das Holzholen, das Inkrafttreten;* […]

---

> **§ 57** Wörter anderer Wortarten schreibt man groß, wenn sie als Substantive gebraucht werden (= Substantivierungen).
>
> […] Man erkennt sie [Substantivierte Wörter] im Text an zumindest einem der folgenden Merkmale:
> a) an einem vorausgehenden Artikel *(der, die, das; ein, eine, ein),* […]

---

> [Unter **§ 57 (2)**]
>
> Bei mehrteiligen Fügungen, deren Bestandteile mit einem Bindestrich verbunden werden, schreibt man das erste Wort, den Infinitiv und die anderen substantivischen Bestandteile groß […], zum Beispiel:
> *es ist zum Auf-und-davon-Laufen, das Hand-in-Hand-Arbeiten, das In-den-Tag-hinein-Leben*

---

> **§ 43** Man setzt Bindestriche in substantivisch gebrauchten Zusammensetzungen (Aneinanderreihungen), […]
>
> E: Dies gilt nicht für übersichtliche Zusammensetzungen mit Infinitiv, zum Beispiel: *das Autofahren, das Ballspielen, beim Walzertanzen, das Inkrafttreten*

---

Damit ergibt sich für die verschiedenen Fragen:

#### Getrennt oder zusammen?

Nach § 37 würde ich *Hieressen* zusammenschreiben, da es sich um eine mehrteilige Substantivierung, nämlich diejenige des Verbkomplexes *hier essen* handelt. Nun wird *hier essen* nicht zusammengeschrieben (»Ich würde gerne hier essen.«), aber das gilt für auch für *Holz holen* (»Irgendwer muss Holz holen.«). Vergleiche auch mit den Beispielen unter § 57 (2).

#### Bindestrich oder nicht?

Was den Bindestrich betrifft, so würde ich die Zusammensetzung als übersichtlich einstufen und gemäß § 43 E keinen Bindestrich setzen. Diese Regel ist aber hinreichend schwammig, dass ich einen Bindestrich nicht als falsch ansähe.

#### Groß- oder Kleinschreibung?

Da im *zum* ein Artikel steckt *(zu dem),* handelt es sich klar um eine Substantivierung und demnach muss irgendetwas großgeschrieben werden.

Schreiben wir ohne Bindestrich, gibt es nur ein Wort und die Antwort ist klar: ***Hieressen.*** (Vergleiche abermals mit dem Beispiel *zum Holzholen* aus § 37.)

Schreiben wir mit Bindestrich, greift die zitierte Passage aus § 57 (2) und es muss sowohl der Infinitiv *(Essen)* als auch das erste Wort *(hier)* großgeschrieben werden, also: ***Hier-Essen***

Comment: Irgendwie bin ich Befürworter der Antwort *Hieressen*. Mit Bindestrich kommt es mir ein bisschen zu behutsam vor – das Zusammenschreiben klingt mutiger.

Comment: Klingt alles schön und gut, aber es wird nicht begründet, warum *hier* und *Essen* eine mehrteilige Fügung sein sollen. Das bezweifle ich nämlich. Es wird zwar behauptet, aber nicht begründet. Das vorgebrachte Beispiel »Holzholen« bzw. »Holz-Holen« ist nämlich ebenso falsch wie »Hieressen«. Und wenn diese Prämisse nicht zutrifft, ist diese Antwort leider wertlos, auch wenn die übrigen Regel korrekt beschrieben und angewendet wurden. Aber »zum hier Essen« enthält keine mehrteilige Fügung.

Comment: Erstmal *brauche* ich § 55 (2) (den mit den mehrteiligen Fügungen) nur für den Fall der Bindestrichschreibung. Die Beispiele darunter bekräftigen meine Aussagen zur Getrennt- oder Zusammenschreibung, mehr nicht. Für das Zusammenschreiben muss es sich lediglich um eine mehrteilige Substantivierung handeln (§ 37). Beachte insbesondere auch, dass *das Holzholen* ein Beispiel direkt aus den offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln ist (unter § 37), und zwar zu der entsprechenden Regel (was ein Versehen ziemlich unwahrscheinlich macht).

Answer (score 9):

Erst einmal sollte man festhalten, dass diese Frage kein vollständiger Satz, sondern eine Ellipse ist. Der vollständige Satz könnte so lauten:

> Möchten Sie die bestellten Speisen **zum Mitnehmen oder zum hier Essen** haben?

Die Konstruktion ist also in Ordnung (es ist eine Ellipse), und ich habe selbstverständlich auch gleich die korrekte Schreibweise verwendet.

Der Verkäufer fragt also formal nach dem Verwendungszweck. Tatsächlich will er aber wissen:

> Soll ich die bestellten Speisen einpacken oder auf einem Tablett servieren?

In Deutschland will der Verkäufer zugleich auch wissen, mit welchem Mehrwertsteuersatz er den Kauf in die Buchhaltung eintragen soll, weil dort für Gassenverkauf ein anderer Steuersatz (nämlich 7 %) gilt als für Speisen, die im Lokal verzehrt werden (19 %). (In Österreich gibt es diesen Unterschied nicht, es werden immer 20 % fällig)

Bleiben wir aber bei der formalen Frage nach dem Zweck. Die eine Möglichkeit ist:

> zum Mitnehmen

*Mitnehmen* ist ein Verb, das hier substantiviert wird, also wie ein Nomen gebraucht wird. Denn das Wort *zum* ist eine Verkürzung von *zu dem*. *Dem* wiederum ist ein Artikel (bestimmt, Singular, Dativ), und daran kann man erkennen, dass das Wort, auf das sich *zu dem* bzw. *zum* bezieht, ein Nomen sein muss, das mit großem Anfangsbuchstaben zu schreiben ist.

Die andere Möglichkeit ist:

> zum (...) Essen

Die Konstruktion erfolgt exakt nach demselben Schema wie soeben beschrieben.

Fehlt noch das Wort **hier**:
Dabei handelt es sich um eine Beifügung (ein Attribut), und zwar wird hier ein lokales Adverb attributiv verwendet. Lokale Adverbien sind Wörter wie *außen, oben, vorne, überall* oder eben auch *hier*, die einen Ort angeben. Einige wenige von ihnen haben zusätzlich die besondere Eigenschaft, als Attribut eines Nomens verwendet werden zu können. Neben *da* und *dort* gehört auch *hier* in diese kleine Gruppe.

Zusammenfassung:

> zum = Verschmelzung von **zu** und **dem**
>   zu = Präposition
>   dem = bestimmter Artikel, Singular, Dativ
>   hier = attributiv verwendetes lokales Adverb
>   Essen = substantiviertes Verb

Comment: »Einige wenige von ihnen haben zusätzlich die besondere Eigenschaft, als Attribut eines Nomens verwendet werden zu können.« – Kannst Du mir ein Beispiel nennen, wo diese (insb. *hier)* als Attribut für ein Nomen verwendet werden, das kein Partizip oder keine Substantivierung ist? Denn in diesen Fällen kann ich auch jedes andere Attribut anwenden: »Ich hätte das gerne zum Um-Mitternacht-bei-Mondschein-Essen.«

Comment: Und ganz nebenbei: Wie beantwortet dies die eigentliche Frage?

Comment: Im ersten Moment dachte ich: Hey, geniale Erklärung. Aber dann muss ich @Wrzlprmft recht geben. Du implizierst zwar, dass es "zum hier Essen" sein soll, nur gehst du gar nicht auf den Punkt ein.

Comment: c.p. hat leider keine klare Frage gestellt (Der Titel ist kein Fragesatz, und im Beitrag steht auch kein ganzer Fragesatz). Aber ich nahm an, dass er folgendes fragen wollte: »1. Ist die Konstruktion *zum Mitnehmen oder zum hier Essen* in Ordnung? 2. Wie schreibt man *zum hier Essen*?«. Meine Antwort analysiert diese Konstruktion und stellt damit klar, dass sie in Ordnung ist und sie gibt auch die korrekte Schreibweise an. Folglich glaube ich, dass meine Antwort genau das beantwortet was c.p. wissen wollte.

Comment: So, jetzt habe ich nach dem ersten Zitat noch einen Satz eingefügt, damit auch explizit ausgesprochen wird, was meine Antwort ohnehin ausdrückt.

Comment: Lokales Adverb als Attribut eines Nomens, das weder ein Partizip noch eine Substantivierung ist: »Das Haus hier gehört meinem Vater.« **Haus**: ein Nomen, das weder ein Partizip noch eine Substantivierung ist. **hier**: attributiv verwendetes lokales Adverb.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Stimmt, aber auch hier nimmt *hier* keine besondere Rolle ein, da ich eine ähnliche Konstruktion mit jedem Attribut bauen kann: »Das Essen um Mitternacht bei Mondschein erhöht die Nährstoffaufnahme.« (Verwende außerdem bitte @-Antworten, sonst kann es sein, dass ich das übersehe.)

Comment: Was mir fehlt sind ganz klar Argumente pro "zum hier Essen". Wrzlprmft hat in seiner Antwort für "zum Hieressen" oder "zum Hier-Essen" plädiert. Du stellst leider nur fest: "Das ist so". Warum? Aus dem Bauch heraus hätte ich auch "zum hier Essen" geschrieben, aber die andere Antwort klingt plausibler. (Hab mich noch nicht entschieden, wer nun Recht behält.)

Comment: Ist es nicht klar, dass *„Folglich muss man auch die richtig schreiben können. Wie?“* das gleiche wie *„Wie kann man diese Konsruktion richtig schreiben“* bedeutet? Hätte ich den ganzen Fragesatz geschrieben, so würde der völlig überflüssig klingen.

Answer (score 4):

Wenn Infinitive ohne Artikel oder nähere Bestimmung stehen, ist oft nicht offensichtlich, ob es sich um einen verbalen Infinitiv (mit Kleinschreibung) oder um einen substantivierten Infinitiv (mit Großschreibung) handelt. Bei dem in der Frage gegebenen Beispiel handelt es sich allerdings eindeutig um einen substantivierten Infinitiv mit *zum* wie z. B.:

> Sie ist vor lauter Arbeit kaum *zum Trinken* gekommen.

Laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* können substantivierte Infinitive komplex sein, d. h., dem Infinitiv als letztem Bestandteil können andere Bestandteile eines Kompositums oder ähnlicher Bildungen vorausgehen. Auch hier gilt Großschreibung:

> das Sichverlieben
>   das allmähliche Sichzusammenballen der Gruppenaggression
>   beim Billardspielen
>   am Zustandekommen
>   ein Rezept zum Reichwerden
>   zum Schlankwerden

Eine ähnliche Erklärung findet man in Duden – *Die Grammatik:* Wenn die mit Verben verbundenen Ergänzungen und Umstandsbestimmungen bei der Substantivierung als deren Bestimmungswörter auftreten, wird dabei gewöhnlich die betreffende Fügung in einem Zug substantiviert:

> Die Kinder lachen. – das Kinderlachen
>   Die Blätter werden gelb. – das Gelbwerden der Blätter

Festgewordene Fügungen, die nur noch in Zusammenschreibung üblich sind, sind beispielsweise

> das Inkrafttreten
>   das Zuspätkommen

Diese Schreibweise entspricht § 37 (2) des Regelwerks zur deutschen Rechtschreibung, wonach man mehrteilige Substantivierungen zusammenschreibt, sowie § 57, wonach man substantivierte Wörter großschreibt.

Somit ist die Schreibweise *zum Hieressen* gemäß dem Regelwerk richtig und gemäß den Erklärungen im Duden nicht ungewöhnlich.

---

Wenn bei der Substantivierung unübersichtliche und schwer lesbare Aneinanderreihungen entstehen, schreibt man laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* substantivierte Infinitive mit mehreren Bestandteilen mit Bindestrichen. Dabei werden dann immer das erste Wort der Gruppe und der am Schluss stehende substantivierte Infinitiv großgeschrieben, außerdem selbstverständlich auch alle in der Fügung vorkommenden Substantive.

Diese Schreibweise entspricht § 43 des Regelwerks zur deutschen Rechtschreibung, wonach man Bindestriche in substantivisch gebrauchten Zusammensetzungen (insbesondere bei substantivisch gebrauchten Infinitiven mit mehr als zwei Bestandteilen) setzt, sowie § 57 (2), wonach man bei mehrteiligen Fügungen, deren Bestandteile mit einem Bindestrich verbunden werden, das erste Wort, den Infinitiv und die anderen substantivischen Bestandteile großschreibt.

Diese Schreibweise gilt jedoch laut § 43 E ausdrücklich nicht für übersichtliche Zusammensetzungen mit Infinitiv wie z. B.

> das Autofahren
>   das Ballspielen
>   beim Walzertanzen
>   das Inkrafttreten

und somit auch nicht für *zum Hieressen.*