# Zusammengesetzte Adjektive — Wie ist die korrekte Großschreibung, wenn substantiviert?

Tags: adjective, spelling, capitalization

Wenn man zusammengesetzte Adjektive wie "nicht existierend" oder "vorher existierend" substantiviert, schreibt man:

> Das nicht Existierende, das vorher Existierende

oder

> Das Nicht Existierende, das Vorher Existierende

Das heißt, werden beide großgeschrieben oder nur die eigentlichen Adjektive?

Und was ist mit den Adjektiven, die durch Bindestrich verbunden sind, wie "nicht-englischsprachig"?

Comment: Verwandter, aber nicht identischer Fall: [Zum „Hieressen“, „hier Essen“ oder „Hier-Essen“?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/20475/2594)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Weder noch.**

Die freien Begleiter in einer Nominalphrase müssen KNG-kongruent* flektiert werden, nicht flektierbare Begleiter müssen fest an den Kopf (also das Substantiv bzw. substantivierte Nichtsubstantiv) gebunden werden.

> *das wahre Existierende, des wahren Existierenden …*

Freie Begleiter *können* auch Teil eines Substantivs werden, vor allem wenn sie sich nur auf den ersten Teil eines Kompositums beziehen.

> *der Rote*(*s*)*-Kreuz-Helfer → der Rotkreuzhelfer*

Da sowohl *nicht* als auch *vorher* nicht flektierbare Partikeln sind (und wir nicht auf *nichtig* und *vorherig* o.ä. ausweichen können oder wollen), erhalten wir folgendes:

> *das Nichtexistierende, das Vorherexistierende*

Optional kann der Bindestrich bei solchen Verbindungen gesetzt werden, was relativ häufig auch passiert (z.B. *Nicht-Ich*):

> *das Nicht-Existierende, das Vorher-Existierende*

Mit *nicht* fallen mir dazu einige Beispiele ein, *vorher* ist eher selten in dieser Funktion. Seine Bestandteile *vor* und *her* sind üblicher und ersteres bietet sich evtl. als Ersatz an:

> *das Nichtexistierende, das Vorexistierende*

In Fremdwörtern ist *prä-* (wie *non-*) ein gängiges Präfix(!), das sowohl zeitliche wie räumliche Bedeutung haben kann. Da *existieren* ein Fremdwort ist, könnte man sich entsprechend auch dafür entscheiden, aber dann würde ich *existent* dem deutschen Partizip vorziehen:

> *das Nonexistierende, das Präexistierende*
>   *das Nonexistente, das Präexistente*

Wer es wirklich deutsch haben möchte, wird auf *sein* zurückgreifen müssen:

> *das Nichtseiende, das Vorherseiende/Vorseiende*

Fügt man allerdings Modifikatoren zu den Partikeln hinzu, kommt man wieder in das Dilemma mit dem Saft aus schwarzen Johannisbeeren. Sollte man sich dann doch für die Getrenntschreibung entscheiden, bleiben die Anfangsbuchstaben der Begleiter auf jeden Fall Minuskeln (wie in der ersten Variante in der Frage).

> *?das schon vorher Existierende – ?das Schonvorherexistierende – *das schon Vorherexistierende*
>   *?das lange vorher Existierende – ?das Langvorherexistierende – *das lange Vorherexistierende*

Solche stilistischen und orthographischen Zweifelsfälle sollten dazu ermuntern, die Substantivierung an sich in Frage zu stellen.

---

*) KNG = Kasus, Numerus und Genus

Comment: Super wäre noch ein Beispiel mit flektierbaren Begleitern zum Vergleich.

Comment: *Die freien Begleiter in einer Nominalphrase müssen KNG-kongruent flektiert werden, nicht flektierbare Begleiter müssen fest an den Kopf (also das Substantiv bzw. substantivierte Nichtsubstantiv) gebunden werden.* – Ich bin jetzt mal absichtlich pingelig: Das erfasst Genetivattribute, Nebensätze u. Ä. nicht.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ja, man könnte das feiner aufdröseln. Hier umfasst „freie Begleiter“ im Wesentlichen Adjektive, Artikel und Pronomen.

Answer (score 6):

<sup>Diese Antwort verfolgt eine andere Herangehensweise als [Crissovs](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/27233/2594), kommt aber weitestgehend zum gleichen Ergebnis:</sup>

§ 37 der Rechtschreibregeln lautet:

> […] Partikeln können mit Substantiven Zusammensetzungen bilden. Man schreibt sie ebenso wie mehrteilige Substantivierungen zusammen.
>
> Dies betrifft
>
> (1) Zusammensetzungen:
>
> […]
>
> (1.5) mit Elementen unflektierter Wortarten (Adverbien, Partikeln):
> *Jetztzeit, Nichtraucher, Selbstverständnis*
>
> […]
>
> (2) Mehrteilige Substantivierungen, zum Beispiel:
> *das Holzholen, das Inkrafttreten; der Kehraus, das Stelldichein, das
> Vergissmeinnicht*

Das *Nichtexstierende* und *Vorherexistierende* sind entweder Zusammensetzung aus Partikel und Substantiv (z. B. *nicht + Existierende*) oder mehrteilige Substantivierungen (z. B. von *nicht existierend*). Was von den beiden sie sind, ist letztlich Geschmackssache und hängt nur davon ab, ob man zuerst zusammensetzt oder zuerst substantiviert. Insbesondere hat es keine weitere Auswirkung und im Endergebnis werden die Wörter zusammengeschrieben.

---

Nun zum Bindestrich: Die einzige Regel, die einen Bindestrich an dieser Stelle zulassen kann, ist § 45, welcher besagt:

> Man kann einen Bindestrich setzen zur Hervorhebung einzelner Bestandteile, zur Gliederung unübersichtlicher Zusammensetzungen, […]
>
> Dies betrifft
>
> (1) Hervorhebung einzelner Bestandteile, zum Beispiel:
>
> *der dass-Satz, die Ich-Erzählung, das Ist-Aufkommen, die Kann-Bestimmung, die Soll-Stärke; die Hoch-Zeit, das Nach-Denken, Vor-Sätze,
> be-greifen*
>
> (2) unübersichtliche Zusammensetzungen, zum Beispiel:
>
> *Arbeiter-Unfallversicherungsgesetz, Haushalt-Mehrzweckküchenmaschine, Lotto-Annahmestelle, Mosel-Winzergenossenschaft, Software-Angebotsmesse, Ultraschall-Messgerät*

Ob diese Regeln hier greifen, ist in in einem gewissen Maße Meinungssache. Ich denke, man kann einen Bindestrich nach Absatz 1 rechtfertigen, da *nicht* betont werden soll. Einen Bindestrich in *Vorher-Existierende* kann man auch nach Absatz 2 rechtfertigen, da man sonst erstmal *Vor-herexistierende* lesen könnte.

In jedem Fall ist der Bindestrich nicht verpflichtend.

Answer (score -3):

Gemäß der Substantivierungsregeln würde ich folgendes für richtig erachten:

> das nicht Existierende, das vorher Existierende

Auch wenn ich keine konkrete Regel dazu im Duden finden konnte, erscheint mir dies als richtig. Dennoch erscheint mir eine Substantivierung von "existierend" auch nicht gerade passend und wirkt "unfertig". Deshalb rate ich dir stilmäßig eher davon ab.

Comment: Ich habe den ersten Absatz mal rausgenommen. Ich hatte die Frage bereits editiert und jetzt erst bemerkt, dass du darauf Bezug genommen hast. Da es aber für die Frage irrelevant ist, habe ich auch deine Antwort abgeändert, anstatt den Fehler in der Frage wieder einzubauen.

Comment: Ich denke, die Antwort ist falsch. Zu _das Existierende_ habe ich kein Beispiel gefunden, aber hier findet sich _die Nichtexistenz_ (http://hpd.de/node/3458)

Comment: @Iris, to be or not to be that's the question(das Sein oder Nichtsein das ist die Frage) maybe :-\