# What's the correct way of capitalising/hyphenating a nominalised verb-verb compound?

Tags: compound, capitalization, hyphen

> Zum *Wegwerfen* ist es zu schade!

… is a clear case, since "zum" has to be followed by a noun, which then has to be capitalised.

But what about …

> Zum *vergammeln lassen* ist es zu schade!

What's the correct capitalisation and hyphenation (if any) for a nominalised compound word like this?

Comment: Related: [Zum „Hieressen“, „hier Essen“ oder „Hier-Essen“?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/20475/2594)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to § 37 (2) of the [official spelling rules](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf), multi-part nominalizations are generally written as one word (which, being a noun, is then capitalized as usual):

> Zum Vergammelnlassen ist es zu schade.

In more complex compounds, hyphens are used to separate the parts (§ 43):

> Zum In-den-Mülleimer-Werfen ist es zu schade.

In these cases, the first word, the infinitive itself, and any noun parts are to be capitalized, as regulated in § 57 (2).

Comment: BTW: a web version of the official rules is available at http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/index.html .