# Substantivierung von sesshaft und werden

Tags: verb, noun

Ich möchte den Satzanfang

> Als die Menschheit sesshaft wurde, […]

ungefähr so umschreiben:

> Mit dem Sesshaftwerden der Menschheit […]

Ist *Sesshaftwerden* hier richtig? Oder sollte ich lieber *Sesshaft-Werden* verwenden. Oder welche Alternative gibt es?

Comment: Willkommen beim Stack Exchange der Deutschen Sprache und vielen Dank für Deine Frage. Wenn Du magst, kannst Du die [tour] nehmen oder Dich im [help] umsehen. Viel Spaß! :)

Comment: Es gibt auch heute noch Nomaden …

Comment: Related: [Zum „Hieressen“, „hier Essen“ oder „Hier-Essen“?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/20475/9551)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Sesshaftwerden" ist ok. Wird nicht gerade häufig verwendet, aber es ist verständlich. Es wird auch in der deutschen Wikipedia benutzt in folgendem Artikel: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesshaftigkeit.

Comment: Auch der Duden nutzt das Wort "Sesshaftwerden" in einem Artikel: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bau

Comment: Wikipedia als offizielle Quelle stehe ich skeptisch gegenüber, dagegen gefällt mir der Eintrag im Duden besser. Danke!

Comment: @Phil Vorsicht, der Duden hat gelegentlich die Neigung, auf
sehr ungebräuchlichen Wörten bzw. Schreibweisen zu beharren
(bekannte Fälle in der Dudengeschichte sind "Schmant" und "Kautsch"). Um herauszufinden,
welche Wörter üblicherweise verwendet werden (erst recht in der
Fachsprache), eignet er sich nur bedingt.

Comment: Neben "Sesshaftwerden" ist auch "Sesshaftwerdung" verbreitet.

Comment: @Uwe gibt es dann andere verwertbare Quellen? Ich muss mich ja auf "gesetzeskonforme" Rechtschreibung berufen, wenn ich offizielle Dokumente erstelle. Meines Wissens nach gelten die Formulierungen des Dudens trotzdem.

Comment: @Phil Lange Antwort, darum in zwei Teilen:

Geht es Dir primär um die Wortbildung
("Sesshaftwerden" oder "Sesshaftwerdung")
oder um die Rechtschreibung
("Sesshaftwerden" oder "Sesshaft-Werden")?
Rechtschreibwörterbucher wie der Duden beschreiben ausschließlich
die Rechtschreibung, sie beantworten nicht die Frage,
welche von mehreren möglichen
Substantivierungen die (in der Fachliteratur) üblichere
ist.
Dazu würde ich eher in die Fachliteratur oder in Google Ngrams
schauen (Antwort: "Sesshaftwerdung").

Comment: Um die Rechtschreibung zu klären, eignet sich im Prinzip jedes
Wörterbuch. Dabei sollte man ein paar Dinge beachten:
(1) Das Dudenprivileg ("maßgeblich ich allen Zweifelsfällen")
wurde mit der Rechtschreibreform abgeschafft.
(2) Zuweilen vertreten einzelne Wörterbücher das,
was Juristen als *Mindermeinung* bezeichnen ("Schmant").
(3) Ein Wort existiert nicht erst dann,
wenn es im Wörterbuch steht; das gilt erst recht
für fachsprachliche Begriffe.
(4) Wenn man für einen Auftraggeber schreibt, dann zählt
dessen Wille (Hausstil,
Binnen-I, Leerzeichen statt Bindestrich)
mehr als jedes Wörterbuch.

Answer (score 3):

Alternativ könnte man auch von der *Verbreitung der Sesshaftigkeit* (oder ähnliche Konstrukte, je nach Kontext) reden. Das würde den Prozess-Charakter hervorheben (auch heute noch nicht abgeschlossen) und den expliziten Bezug auf die Menschheit entfernen.

Comment: Wäre auch möglich, ich möchte mir hier jedoch gerade auf die Menschheit beziehen. Ich hätte wohl den ganzen Satz angeben sollen ;)